# Where should I define DISALLOW_COPY_AND_ASSIGN macro in Xcode

Tags: c++, xcode, macros

I tried to set

```
#define DISALLOW_COPY_AND_ASSIGN(TypeName) \
  TypeName(const TypeName&);               \
  void operator=(const TypeName&)
```

in xcode's build setting, Apple LLVM compile 4.2 - Preprocessing -> Preprocessor Macros.

But, it seems for me Xcode does not allow this function-style macro.

How can I define this macro for any file in this project.

Comment: It's just a guess, but it might be that the IDE can't handle multi-line macro bodies? Try putting it all as a single line.

Comment: Why not just put it in your `.pch` file, which every file implicitly includes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not just put it in your `.pch` file, which every file implicitly includes